# Not able to deploy terraform resource"azurerm_network_interface.main" using azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to deploy infra(terraform) using azure pipeline. I am using a script which deploys the infra but the infra creation stuck in the creation state for long time where as if I deploy using my local I am able to deploy it easily and within few minutes

The pipeline stuck in the creating state and fails after 1hour while on my local I am able to deploy within 5-6mins
[image]

Here is the provider details :

```
terraform {

  required_version = ">=0.12"

  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.90.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
```

Comment: Hello @so9868 , May I  know what are the permissions assigned to the service account that you are using in azure devops ? Does the  operation  fail with any error ?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT the role assigned is contributor and the error message with which the pipeline fails is "##[error]The job running on agent Hosted Agent ran longer than the maximum time of 60 minutes. For more information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077134"

The pipeline creates few of the resources like security group and resource group with stuck in the creation phase of network interface and security group association

Comment: Hello @so9868, can you share the code that you are using , so that i can test it from my environment

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same and was facing the issue like below:

[image]

So , as a solution I just added a `depends on` block on the ***subnet nsg association*** as below:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "example" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.example.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.example.id
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_network_interface.example
  ]
}
```

***It resolved the issue like below :***

[image]

Comment: Glad to be of help !! :)